# How to display two taxonomy terms on multi taxonomy category page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am currently trying to extend my sites beyond the typical category -> posts structure and get more specific with pages that target multiple taxonomies. Basically here is what I want to do.

- I have a Custom Post Type set up, and each custom post in in multiple taxonomies and can have multiple values in each taxonomy. So CPT1 can have Tax1 values of Blue and Red and Tax2 values of Widgets and Fidgets.
- I currently have it working where pages like site.com/tax1/red/widgets/ works as a valid URL and it returns the correct set of posts within the CPT. Awesome! That code is here:

  //trying to create pages for eg /tax1/tax1value/tax2value/
  function custom_rewrite_rules() {
      add_rewrite_rule('^tax1/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?
  tax1=$matches[1]&tax2=$matches[2]', 'top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');

Now I am running into an issue that is currently above my skill level. I'm trying to:

- Make the , , and  on the page reflect both values (eg "red" and "widgets") so that the  will say "Red Widgets". Currently, it just says "widgets".

Things I notice and have tried:

- The page site.com/tax1/red/widgets/ is using the taxonomy.php template page, but seems to be pulling the tax2 . So instead of having a class of tax-tax1 within the  tag, I get tax2 (which in this case is actually tag, so it shows up as  instead of  like on regular tax1 value pages like site.com/tax1/value-here/)
- I've tried pulling the terms using  but that a) doesn't do anything and b) in my investigations found that this is really for posts, not a combo category page like this.

So, the specific questions:

1. Any links to resources on getting the page site.com/tax1/red/widgets/ to use the taxonomy head/body instead of the tag body like currently?
2. Any links to resources on modifying the query being used so I can display both taxonomy values being used ("red" and "widgets") and not just pull the dominant one (tags in this case)

Thanks so much in advance.